# How to seed the pcg random number generator?

Tags: random, random-seed

In the [samples for PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) they only seed one way which I assume is best/preferred practice:

```
pcg32 rng(pcg_extras::seed_seq_from<std::random_device>{});
```

or

```
// Seed with a real random value, if available
pcg_extras::seed_seq_from<std::random_device> seed_source;

// Make a random number engine 
pcg32 rng(seed_source);
```

However running this on my machine just produces the same seed every time. It is no better then if I just typed in some integer to seed with myself. What would be a good method to seed if trying it this way doesn't work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pcg_extras::seed_seq_from` is supposed to be the recommended way, but it delegates the actual seed generation to the generator specified in the template parameter.

MinGW has a broken implementation of `std::random_device`. So at this moment, if you want to target MinGW, you must not use `std::random_device`.

Some potential alternatives:

- `boost::random_device`
- [randutils](https://gist.github.com/imneme/540829265469e673d045), by the author of PCG,  M.E. O'Neill
- [`seed11::seed_device`](https://github.com/milleniumbug/seed11/), drop-in replacement for `std::random_device` (disclaimer: it's my own library)

More info about seeding in [this blog post by M.E. O'Neill](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/simple-portable-cpp-seed-entropy.html).